# I want to connect and display two tables from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i want to use inner join to connect these two tables but i'm not sure how.

This is the php code for now.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM reservation ORDER BY reserve_id desc";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

and I want to connect these two tables by using inner join so I can see who chose which table in the reservation and I don't want other people to make a reservation on the same time and same tables as others.

[image: Here you can see reservations]

[image: here you can see the tables]

Comment: Your reservations don't include any table information.  So, when a reservation is made it's **only** for a time, not for a specific table.  This means that there's no concept as "a reservation for the same table as others".  Also, you don't explain what the `tables` data ***means***.  Table #4 says `available = 0`, but has no date or time information.  Does that mean Table #4 is never and will never be available for use?  Or does it just mean it's not available "right now"?  In short, it's not clear what you want to achieve, and there's not enough information to work it out for you.

Comment: I think you should read this, then edit and clarify your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MatBailie table_nr is table number and If the table is available it's 1 and if not it's 0 so it means that table #4 is not available right now. i just want people that are making a reservation to choose only from the available tables which have the value 1.

Comment: It seems you have already asked that same question. I close this one in favour of the old one. Please do as you are asked instead of reposting the same question again.